# How to get boost.python tutorial example to link with Python3: Raspberry Pi3 / boost 1.72 (linux)

Tags: python, c++, linux, boost

I'm new to boost. I've tried to get boost.python running without success.

When I enter b2 in /home/pi/Desktop/boost_1_72_0/libs/python/example/quickstart I get the following message:

```
...found 15 targets...
...updating 1 target...
gcc.link embedding
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    "g++" -L"/usr/lib" -Wl,-rpath -Wl,"/usr/lib"  -o "embedding" -Wl,--start-group "embedding.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lboost_python -ldl -lpthread -lutil -lpython3.5 -Wl,--end-group -fPIC -g 
...failed gcc.link embedding...
...failed updating 1 target...
```

The user-confi.jam file contains the following line:

```
using python : 3.5 : /usr/bin/python3.5 : /usr/include/python3.5 : /usr/lib ;
```

Existing:
/usr/bin/python3.5 (file)
/usr/include/python3.5 (directory)

However, there is no directory like /usr/bin/ld.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for your support!